# DB Unit: Testing insert and update operations

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dbunit

How would I test `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations using DB unit?
I am using a fixtures data xml for testing read operations. 
Does it mean that test case would insert/update a row in xml itself? If yes, does DBUnit provides any utility to work with xmld?
Already test methods which tests if table returns one record or multiple records. In these read cases testing is being done by comparing `ITable`s.
 I am not sure what assert in case of create operation. Row count?
Same question goes with `Update` operation. What should a test case assert after doing an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I test `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations using DB unit?

On `INSERT`, verify the row count is +1 and run a `SELECT` searching for the inserted record.

On `UPDATE`, verify that the updated record doesn't match the old record by running a `SELECT` before and after `UPDATE`.

> I am using a fixtures data xml for testing read operations
>   Does it mean that test case would insert/update a row in xml itself?

No. DbUnit reads the XML file and creates a snapshot of it in memory. Your inserts and updates are done in memory so the XMLs are never modified.

> I am not sure what assert in case of create operation. Row count?
>   Same question goes with `Update` operation. What should a test case assert after doing an update?

See the answer to question 1.

Also use http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/ for references.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@ExpectedDatabase` annotation with an appropriate `assertMode`

e.g.

```
@Test
@ExpectedDatabase(value = "result-data.xml")
public void testInsertion() {
    ...
}
```